# Trying to compare groups, why isn't EMMEANS working?

Tags: r, regression, anova, emmeans, ancova

I am trying to perform ANCOVA on my data and determine which groups show a difference in elevation of allometric curves. I'm trying to do a comparison between different groups as such:
GroupA:GroupB, GroupB:GroupC, GroupA:GroupC
I've resorted to using 3 ancovas, each between two groups, because using the emmeans function is not working. There are relationships that are clearly significant which the emmeans caode is not picking up on at all. What kind of post hoc test can I do to get proper pairwise comparisons and only use 1 ANCOVA?

```
  Q.v.Endo_Ext.v.Met<-lm(Q.log~Endo.log*Family, data = CrocaCerCData, subset = Family=='1.Extant'|Family=='2.Metriorhynchid')
    summary(Q.v.Endo_Ext.v.Met)
    anova(Q.v.Endo_Ext.v.Met)
    
    Q.v.Endo_Ext.v.Non<-lm(Q.log~Endo.log*Family, data = CrocaCerCData, subset = Family=='1.Extant'|Family=='2.Non-metriorhynchid')
    summary(Q.v.Endo_Ext.v.Non)
    anova(Q.v.Endo_Ext.v.Non)
    
    Q.v.Endo_Met.V.Non<-lm(Q.log~Endo.log*Family, data= CrocaCerCData, subset = Family=="2.Metriorhynchid"|Family=='2.Non-metriorhynchid')
    summary(Q.v.Endo_Met.V.Non)
    anova(Q.v.Endo_Met.V.Non)
```

Comment: have you tried difflsmeans of the lmerTest package?

Comment: The approach you are trying is pretty inefficient use of data. Am i correct that actually emmeans() is working, but you don't believe the results? Show some output because we can't see what the issue is.

Comment: How can I show my output if the character length is too long?